# scheduleAtFixedRate crash whole app

Tags: java, android, timer, crash, task

I am writing app which generates random numbers and shows them (one after another) on android screen. Here is activity java fragment.

```
public class Scada extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scada);
    Timer timer1= new Timer();
    timer1.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Flow1);
            random flow1=new random();
            myTextView.setText("Flow: " + flow1.random() + " m" + Html.fromHtml("<sup><small>" + "3" + "</small></sup>"));
        }
    },0,9000);
```

**Here is random class (but i think it looks ok)**

```
public class random {

    public int random (){
    Random gen1 = new Random();
    int flow1 = gen1.nextInt(100);
    return  flow1;}
}
```

When I try to use `Timer` app crashed.What is the reason ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry but what is logcat. is ?

Comment: you are android developer and you dont know what log-cat means ???
thats shame... :( :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer runs on a background thread, and you are not allowed to change the UI on a background thread. If your goal is just to change the TextView's content every 9 seconds, you can use a Handler. E.g.

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Flow1);
            random flow1=new random();
            myTextView.setText("Flow: " + flow1.random() + " m" + Html.fromHtml("<sup><small>" + "3" + "</small></sup>"));
            myTextView.postDelayed(this, 9000);
        }
    };
```

and in onCreate, to the same thing:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Flow1);
myTextView.postDelayed(r, 9000);
```

Comment: Thnx a lot that's really helps. I should look deeply to multi threads concept.